# Where is the original big list Linux command?

Tags: command-line

Every day I'm working with Linux command. Today I'm looking for `sed` command.

When searching for it, there is lots of website showing how I can do with it. Usually in a website, its incomplete example and incomplete cheat sheet. When all of that sources combined together, I can get more complete cheat sheet and more complete example.

Until now its still not clear to me about who created all of this command? and where is the original source with complete list of cheat sheet?

Comment: `sed` is a very flexible tool. Showing **all** its possible uses is mathematically (and therefore practically) impossible. That's a bit like saying "give me the complete list of uses for the word 'green'" - the scope of the question is too large to be useful.

Comment: @Piskvor: id's say it is mathematically possible to calculate all uses, but you might have to use [Knuth's up-arrow notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) for a final result ;-)

Comment: @darloo: IIRC, allowing for unlimited input size, the set of all possible inputs should be countably infinite - and don't even go into the topic of metaprograms.

Comment: @Piskvor: assuming unlimited input size, of course. But for a finite input and all possible combinations of sed's command line modifiers (and finite input for them), you can get a number that's not infinite

Answer (score 1):

run `man sed` for a lot of information about this command... ;]

Answer (score 1):

Many commands come from the project GNU.

You can find the documentation of sed at 'http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/' and the source code of sed-4.2.1 [here](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/sed/sed-4.2.1.tar.gz).

Comment: Many predate GNU; the GNU project simply reimplemented them.

Answer (score 0):

These "cheat sheets" aren't lists of cheatcodes like the ones in computer games, they're either lists of many little programs that different people wrote (in that case, you can't collect all) or the documentation, which is complete.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a cheat sheet for sed is a bit like getting a cheat sheet for a programming language - of necessity it will be incomplete, as sed is too big to be encapsulated in one sheet (or web page).  After all, it had a [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1565922255) written about it!  (Okay, to be fair, I've not read the whole thing, but do believe most of it is about awk.)